# Making Network Requests in the Background on watchOS

Tags: watchkit, nsurlsession, apple-watch, watchos, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have a Apple Watch app that let's users record audio and they syncs it with the cloud. Once the user is done recording, I upload the file and some corresponding data.

Problem is that if I use a `defaultSessionConfiguration` for foreground requests, as soon as the app goes into the background (user drops their wrist), the NSURLSession pauses until the app is in the foreground again.

I've tried using a background session but that doesn't seem to work for data tasks. Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: May this help you? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whats-new-in-watchos-3-background-tasks--cms-27126 Section 1 seems to offer some information.

Comment: Have you looked at Apple's WWDC videos from last year?  You can find them on Apple's developer site.  The sample app they used for watch NSURL was a apple pie ordering app that used NSURLSession in the background.  I wouldn't think the data transfer direction would matter, although they used it to wait for a response from a remote server.